# Elemento visível mas ainda não clicavel

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Nos meus testes automatizados com selenium, possuo um método que espera o elemento por um determinado tempo, até que o elemento fique visível na tela (VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy).

Porém, quando o elemento fica visível ele ainda não está clicável, estourando o erro no click. Acontece normalmente quando carrega o elemento, mas a página ainda está carregando.

Comment: Quando falo "ainda não está clicável" me refiro a habilitado para Clique. No meu caso fica a label de Carregando na frente da tela

Answer (score 1):

Além de verificar se o elemento está visível através do método que você citou você pode verificar se o elemento já pode ser clicado através do método elementToBeClickable antes de chamar o método click. Use o wait para esperar o elemento ficar pronto. Veja um exemplo:

```
private static WebDriver driver;
private static WebDriverWait wait;

driver = new chromeDriver();
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); //espera por dez sengundos


static By button = By.id("btnEnviar"); 

public static void clickButton{
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(button));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));
    driver.findElement(button).click();
}
```